# Calculating Extremes of Camera FOV Given Heading and Angle

Tags: matlab, vector, camera, transpose, drone.io

If I have a unit vector **H** - a heading that represents a camera centre of view, how can I calculate corresponding vectors for **H<sub>1</sub>**,   **H<sub>2</sub>**,   **H<sub>3</sub>** and   **H<sub>4</sub>**   that represent the extremes of view given a given number of degrees of total width  **θ<sub>w</sub>** and height  **θ<sub>h</sub>** variation?

I do not need to account for camera 'roll' (pitch and yaw are obviously accounted for within the initial vector).

This is for the purpose of implementing a drone camera simulation.

For example for similar  **θ<sub>w</sub>** and **θ<sub>h</sub>** of 40 degrees, I need

**H<sub>1</sub>** to be  **H**  rotated +20 deg in camera width and + 20 deg in camera height

**H<sub>2</sub>** to be  **H**  rotated +20 deg in camera width and - 20 deg in camera height

... and so on

Answer (score 1):

Use spherical coordinates, make the translation to these and the problem is easy and goes away with simple less or than greater than comparisons.

I chose to work mainly in Cartesian coordinates, then use cart2sph().